# Boto - S3 Response Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, boto

I know there are a lot of questions on here about the same issue , however I have gone through each and every one of them and have tried out the suggestions and answers given there to no avail. Thats why I am posting this question here

I am trying to upload a file to my bucket. Since this file is larger than `100mb` I am trying to upload it using the multipart_upload which `boto` supports. I was able to achieve that . Then i tried to increase upload speeds by using the `pool` class from `multiprocessing` module. I used the code given below . When I run the program, nothing happens. I used the `from multiprocessing.dummy import pool` for debugging purposes and the program raises an

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>55D423C42E8A9D94</RequestId><HostId>kxxX+UmBlGaT4X8adUAp9XQV/1jiiK83IZKQuKxAIMEmzdC3g9IRqDqIVXGLPAOe</HostId></Error>
```

at `raise exc` (marked with a '#') under `_upload`. I dont understand why i get this. I have full read and write access to the bucket and standard uploads work like a charm without any error. I can also delete any file I want from the bucket. The only issue seems to be when I try parallel uploads. Code is pasted below adn can also be found [here](http://www.topfstedt.de/python-parallel-s3-multipart-upload-with-retries.html)

My code:(I have removed my keys and bucket name from the code)

```
def _upload_part(bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, multipart_id, part_num,
                     source_path, offset, bytes, amount_of_retries=10):
    """
    Uploads a part with retries.
    """
    def _upload(retries_left=amount_of_retries):
        try:
            logging.info('Start uploading part #%d ...' % part_num)
            conn = S3Connection(aws_key, aws_secret)
            bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
            for mp in bucket.get_all_multipart_uploads():
                if mp.id == multipart_id:
                    with FileChunkIO(source_path, 'r', offset=offset,
                                     bytes=bytes) as fp:
                        mp.upload_part_from_file(fp=fp, part_num=part_num)
                    break
        except Exception, exc:
            if retries_left:
                _upload(retries_left=retries_left - 1)
            else:
                logging.info('... Failed uploading part #%d' % part_num)
                raise exc  #this line raises error
        else:
            logging.info('... Uploaded part #%d' % part_num)

    _upload()


def upload(bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, source_path, keyname,
               acl='private', headers={}, parallel_processes=4):
    """
    Parallel multipart upload.
    """
    conn = S3Connection(aws_key, aws_secret)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)

    mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(keyname, headers=headers)

    source_size = os.stat(source_path).st_size
    bytes_per_chunk = max(int(math.sqrt(5242880) * math.sqrt(source_size)),
                          5242880)
    chunk_amount = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(bytes_per_chunk)))

    pool = Pool(processes=parallel_processes)
    for i in range(chunk_amount):
        offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
        remaining_bytes = source_size - offset
        bytes = min([bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes])
        part_num = i + 1
        pool.apply_async(_upload_part, [bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, mp.id,
                                        part_num, source_path, offset, bytes])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    if len(mp.get_all_parts()) == chunk_amount:
        mp.complete_upload()
        key = bucket.get_key(keyname)
        key.set_acl(acl)
    else:
        mp.cancel_upload()

upload(default_bucket, acs_key, sec_key, '/path/to/folder/testfile.txt', 'testfile.txt')
```

Comment: It would be instructive to see which line in `try` block generates the exception. In `except` block, please add a line before `if retries_left ...` that logs the original exception like so: `logging.exception("boom!")`

Comment: Added that line. Same error. Prints `boom` on terminal though

Comment: it should also print entire stack trace.

Comment: the line of code that seems to be the problem is `_upload(retries_left = retries -1)`

Comment: OK. let me simplify this: temporarily remove ALL exc handling from your _upload function. Only leave the code you have in the `try` part. And report what exception you get. Your current exc handling logic masks the real problem.

Comment: I did that. While the error remains the same , the stacktrace now highlights the `for mp in bucket.get_all_multipart_uploads():` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71905/discussion-between-pavel-repin-and-letsc).